# How to calculate lowest and highet datum value in boxplot?

Tags: r, boxplot

I am working on calculation of lowest and highest datum. I goggled and found that these lies in 1.5 IQR range of lower and upper quartile but could not find the way to calculate their numerical values.

```
 x<-rnorm(200)
 boxplot(x,horizontal=TRUE,axes=FALSE,outline=FALSE)
```

I need to put 2 points/markers at lowest and highest datum as shown in image.

[image]

Comment: I think it will be usefull for you: `?boxplot.stats`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foo <- boxplot(x,horizontal=TRUE,axes=FALSE,outline=FALSE)
points(foo$stats[c(1,5),1],c(1,1),pch=21,bg="red")
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I couldn't open the OP's image link at first, but it seems like he wants the min and max whisker, so I changed the answer.

Comment: I want values of lowest and highest datum not min/max. In the box plot, i need values on vertical lines shown either side of box.

Comment: Presumably the part of the answer which gives this is `foo$stats[c(1,5),1]`

Answer (score -1):

To get lowest and highest value of Boxplot use this method :

state.x77 #after running this command you will get Matrix chart

## (**PUT BOXPLOT COMMAND IN PARTICULAR OBJECT , I CHOOSE "A" AS A OBJECT**)

A<- boxplot(state.x77$Population)

A # Run A

## after run A you will get $stats,inside this

FIRST value is LOWEST

LAST value is HIGHEST